# new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple python gabor filtering

Tags: windows, python-2.7, image-processing

I am trying to implement gabor filter for enhancing the image .I got a code snippet from google on which i am working on which gave me a error which am not familiar with please guide me through the code attached below so that the error can be corrected.

the which give me error is

```
def gabor(im, W, angles):
    x, y = im.size
    im_load = im.load()

    freqs = frequency.freq(im, W, angles)
    print "computing local ridge frequency done"

    gauss = utils.gauss_kernel(3)
    utils.apply_kernel(freqs, gauss)

    for i in range(1, x / W - 1):
        for j in range(1, y / W - 1):
            kernel = gabor_kernel(W, angles[i][j], freqs[i][j])
            for k in range(0, W):
                for l in range(0, W):
                    im_load[i * W + k, j * W + l] = utils.apply_kernel_at(lambda x, y: im_load[x, y],kernel,i * W + k,j * W + l)

    return im
```

the iterations goes smoothly after the fourth for loop it shows a error in

```
im_load[i * W + k, j * W + l] = utils.apply_kernel_at(lambda x, y: im_load[x, y],kernel,i * W + k,j * W + l)
```

the error says like this

```
    im_load[i * W + k, j * W + l] = utils.apply_kernel_at(lambda x, y: im_load[x, y],kernel,i * W + k,j * W + l)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

**Update**

I found this answer after a few more googling
seems the code never works on python 2.7.10 which i am using 
it works on 2.7.6

**how to make it work in python 2.7.10**

**Update after installing python 2.7.6**

i tried the code after installing python 2.7.6 as stated in a answer in stack overflow but still the error persist.
what to do now?

**update after long testing of code**

i had gone through the code in depth to understand its working found the error code but i am unable to correct it

error is within the function **apply_kernel_at**

```
def apply_kernel_at(get_value, kernel, i, j):
    kernel_size = len(kernel)
    result = 0
    for k in range(0, kernel_size):
        for l in range(0, kernel_size):
            pixel = get_value(i + k - kernel_size / 2, j + l - kernel_size / 2)
            result += pixel * kernel[k][l]
            #print pixel
    return result
```

which returns a single value **result** but the line which uses the function call do require two values

```
im_load[i * W + k, j * W + l]=utils.apply_kernel_at(lambda x, y: im_load[x, y],kernel,i * W + k,j * W + l)
```

i am not sure whether my findings are correct or not

any help would be appreciated.